# Create a Hashmap with enum class in java

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

I have a question which requires me to create an enum class with two fields, name (String), and then create a hashmap to generate the output with foreach loops method here.

Expected output:

1 = APPLE, price = 20

2 = STRAWBERRY, price = 70

I try to create two hashmaps to get the output and for loops to get the value but the output is not what I want. May I know how to print the price with the relevant fruits only?

My output:

1 = APPLE

2 = STRAWBERRY

,price=20

,price=70

Enum code here:

```
enum Fruit {
            APPLE("APPLE", 20), STRAWBERRY("STRAWBERRY", 70);
            private final int price;
            private final String name;
            private Fruit(String name, int price) {
                this.name = name;
                this.price = price;
            }
        }
```

main class here

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           
            HashMap<Integer, Fruit> foodTable = new HashMap<>();
            HashMap<Fruit, Integer> priceTable = new HashMap<>();
            foodTable.put(1, Fruit.APPLE);
            priceTable.put(Fruit.APPLE, Fruit.APPLE.price);
            foodTable.put(2, Fruit.STRAWBERRY);
            priceTable.put(Fruit.STRAWBERRY, Fruit.STRAWBERRY.price);
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Fruit> set : foodTable.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(set.getKey() + " = " + set.getValue());
            }
            for (Map.Entry<Fruit, Integer> set1 : priceTable.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("," +
                        "price" + "=" + set1.getValue());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use a single loop over `foodTable` (like you already do). Inside the loop, use `priceTable.get(set.getValue())` to get the price. Use a single `println` to print the three values (`set.getKey()`, `set.getValue()`, `priceTable.get(set.getValue())`). You can use `System.out.printf("%s = %s, price = %s%n", ...)` for that.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I also want to figure out whether my understanding is right here. As the key of priceTable is pointed to the value of foodTable, thus priceTable.get(set.getValue()) link the value of foodTable, and both key and value of priceTable?

Comment: Indeed. Compare it to a database, where `foodTable.getValue()` links to `priceTable.getKey()`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need maps at all, as an enum provides a method to return its values.

Given the enum

```
enum Fruit {
    APPLE("APPLE", 20), STRAWBERRY("STRAWBERRY", 70);
    private final int price;
    private final String name;
    private Fruit(String name, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getPrice() { return price; }
}
```

You can simply write:

```
int pos = 0;
for (Fruit fruit : Fruit.values()) {
    pos++;
    System.out.printf("%d = %s, price = %d%n", 
            pos, fruit.getName(), fruit.getPrice());
}
```

Edit: as an enum value also knows its ordinal position you can simplify this to

```
for (Fruit fruit : Fruit.values()) {
    System.out.printf("%d = %s, price = %d%n", 
            fruit.ordinal()+1, fruit.getName(), fruit.getPrice());
}
```